# Есть форум или техническая поддержка по GTK библиотеке?

Tags: c++, gtk+

Есть возможность задать вопрос именно разработчикам хоть на английском языке ?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно все есть. Есть такая вот ссылка на комюнити https://www.gtk.org/community/

В принципе она ведет на их гитлаб https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk

Поэтому, если есть вопрос по какой то конкретной части гтк, можно открыть сорцы найти этот файл, найти, кто там коммитил (blame) и увидеть имена реальных разработчиков. Некоторые из них вполне легко нагуглить или прям там открыть issue с вопросом.

Там же можно найти ссылку на https://discourse.gnome.org/